# What to enter into browser-sync command to run it on Aquia Dev Desktop?

Tags: acquia-dev-desktop

I'm trying to set up Broswers-Sync for my Aquia Dev Desktop Drupal 7 installation on localhost

In the page tutorial it says to set up local host like this command:

```
browser-sync start --proxy "myproject.dev" --files "css/*.css"
```

But I'm not sure what to put in there for my actual project.

The file I want to target is:

```
C:\patch\sites\all\themes\bootstrap_subtheme_local\css\style.css
```

And site URL on my machine is:

```
http://patch.dd:8083/
```

I want to know what to put in the command line to make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the hostname and port (patch.dd:8083) and the path to the CSS files you want to watch. Using the values in your example, you should therefore run:

```
browser-sync start --proxy "patch.dd:8083" --files "C:\patch\sites\all\themes\bootstrap_subtheme_local\css\style.css"
```

Comment: Hi Nic, yes indeed this is working, it DOES open the website in the window, but changing css does nothing after saving, need to refresh...using Notepad++, am I missing something? URL says http://localhost:3000/ so everything should work?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the fix, I used...

The problem was that localhost:3000 isn't actually connected to http://yourblogname.dd:8080/- you can verify this by going to localhost:3001 (or the UI port shown on your console) and you should see that while using aquia dev desktop, there is no connection unless you go to yourblogname.dd/3000

To fix this, I've used an external call, that will change the output localhost:3000 to myblogname:3000

```
gulp.task('browserSync', function() {
    //note: special fix for aquia dev desktop, to get mybog.dd
    browserSync.init({
       open: 'external',
       host: 'yourblogname.dd',
       proxy: 'http://yourblogname.dd:8080/', // or project.dev/app/
   });
});
```